# What’s supposed to happen if a person gives the “wrong” answers during check in on a U.S.-bound flight?

Tags: usa, air-travel

When checking in for an international flight to the US, one is often asked questions like “what’s your travel plan?” or “what do you do for work?”  These questions can be asked even if one is a US citizen, so they’re not about immigration compliance.

But… what’s supposed to happen if one gives the “wrong” answers to those questions? Is the airline supposed to deny them boarding or just scan their bags extra hard?

Comment: Do you mean question asked by check-in/boarding crew?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi correct, asked by check in crew

Comment: I don't think I've ever been asked about work by an airline agent. I've been asked "Do you have an onward ticket" and "do you have a visa", both of which serve the airline's immigration obligations. In what country were you asked about work?

Comment: @Sneftel Prague airport, Delta flight, this morning

Comment: Weeeird. Maybe they're hiring, and wanted to see if you were available :-)

Comment: About 15-20 years ago at the height of terrorism fears following 9/11 and other schemes, they were doing pre-screening at UK airports on flights to the USA where they'd ask questions about purpose of travel and stuff (often while queuing for check-in rather than at the check-in desk). El Al has long had a policy of doing screening at check-in on many of its flights due to its heightened risk of terrorism. So it's possible if there is a particular security risk, but it's not normal (especially as many people won't even check in at the desk for most flights, unless forced to.)

Comment: have you heard of Guantanamo?

Comment: "About 15-20 years ago at the height of terrorism fears following 9/11 and other schemes, they were doing pre-screening at UK airports on flights to the USA where they'd ask questions about purpose of travel and stuff (often while queuing for check-in rather than at the check-in desk)" they still do that today, mostly to make sure you have an ESTA etc.

Comment: In many cases this is handled by dedicated “security” agents from companies like ICTS rather than actual airline agents or ground handlers. I’m not sure there are really right or wrong questions (this is not an immigration check, it’s security related), they are probably just try to gauge people’s reactions (I.e. how nervous one is), which could lead to further questioning, and in the worst case, reporting to CBP which would take the dreaded DO NOT BOARD decision.

Answer (score 2):

If the question are given by airline personals (or ground personal hired by the airline), there is not much to worry.

They may ask the first question (and maybe the second one), to asses your wiliness to change plans. Sometime international flights are "overbooked", in classical sense, but also they may have passengers that want to flight back (e.g. for emergency reasons, and so they are willing to pay much more to airline). So you may get asked more discretely if you can change your plan (and they may make you an offer). If you later travel to a different city, they may have also more options to get your there. Note: for overbooking (maybe just because they need to change plane type), they may get information about your wiliness to settle with a lower offer (so they may try to pick the "right" person). The first case if voluntary, so there is no "wrong answer", but on the second case you may get in the wrong list.

Or such questions could be done if they notice something strange on you. Nervous flyer? Drunk? Etc. In such case they may look for you (reassure you more, or not putting your near an emergency exit, or just you will have an additional look (to be sure you will not cause troubles). So, they do not care much about the answer, but on how do you answer (nervous, confused, very slow [but you are a native speaker], etc.).

If government cared about such answers, the government would put them in the API (Advanced Passenger Information).

About officer (border control, immigration, etc.)? Do not lie. They may use "wrong answers" as a shortcut for a ban (for non US citizens). They will check your records only when you got on their radar for other reasons. But for US citizens such shortcut doesn't exist.

Comment: Has nothing to do with overbooking as this never happens on domestic flights which get overbooked just as often statistically.

Comment: On domestic flight, they do not need it: there are many alternatives. But in a queue oversee Delta crew asked me similar questions, but then they stopped on next passenger to give them an offer to change flight (hotel + next day flight). I have no idea on what was the answer of next passenger, but they ask me plan and flexibility.

Comment: Airlines are more likely to overbook long-haul flights than domestic, because for the former they want to get the maximum number of people (money) on a daily flight, while on the latter it's often more important to offer frequent flights even if they're not 100% full.